# Angular2 Service Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular2-services

For some reason my services aren't working. I've been lurking SO for two days trying to find similar questions, but they don't fit my problem.

Service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { CarObject } from './make';

@Injectable()
export class EdmundsService {
  private stylesurl = 'REDACTED';

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

 getCars(): Observable<CarObject[]> {
   return this.http.get(this.stylesurl)
   .map(this.extractData)
   .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
   let body = res.json();
   return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
   let errMsg: string;
   if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
     } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

These are my 'models':

```
class Style {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  make: Make;
  model: Model;
  year: Year;
  submodel: Submodel;
  trim: string;
  states: string[];
  engine: Engine;
  transmission: Transmission;
  options: Options[];
  colors: Color[];
  drivenWheels: string;
  numOfDoors: string;
  squishVins: string[];
  categories: Categories;
  MPG: MPG;
  manufacturerOptionCode: string;
 }

export class CarObject {
styles: Style[];
stylesCount: number;
}
```

My component:

```
import { CarObject } from './make';
import { EdmundsService } from './edmunds-search-result.service';

@Component({REDACTED
providers: [EdmundsService] })


export class EdmundsSearchResultComponent implements OnInit {
  cars: CarObject[];
  errorMessage: string;



  constructor(private _edmundsService: EdmundsService) { }

   getCars(): void {
     this._edmundsService.getCars()
     .subscribe(
      cars => this.cars = cars,
      error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }


  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getCars();
  }

}
```

Component HTML:
    {{ cars.stylesCount | async }}

Sample API Response: http://pastebin.com/0LyZuPGW

Error Output:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./EdmundsSearchResultComponent class 
EdmundsSearchResultComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: 
Cannot read    property 'stylesCount' of undefined
```

1. CarObject was designed to match the API Response, so it could be okay to remove the array brackets ( [] )
2. I don't know why this won't display the object data on my template despite closely following the Tour Of Heroes HTTP/Services tutorial.

What I am trying to do is make an HTTP request from variable 'styleurl' (which I see is successfully made by checking the 'Network' tab in chrome dev tools.) Using this API Response, I want my CarObject to 'consume' the json response, and be available to my component/template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to pass form data from html(view) to it's associated component in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093772/not-able-to-pass-form-data-from-htmlview-to-its-associated-component-in-angul)

Comment: Though the questions aren't same but the answer is same for both questions.Check my answer in the question above.

Comment: @SabbirRahman I looked at your answer and I still don't understand what to do. Please be more explicit.

Comment: You are trying to access `stylesCount` property of the `cars` object which is undefined when the template first try to access it. To solve this you just have to assign an empty object to cars object when declaring. `declare cars: any = {}`. If you don't want to use `any` you have to assign the a default object instead of {}.

Comment: @SabbirRahman I have replaced my `cars: CarObject;` with `declare cars: any = {}` and received the following error `(15,3): declare modifier cannot appear on a class element.)`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant to say declare `cars: any = {};` Didn't wanterd to highlight the word 'declare'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your component you're reserving your `car` property, but you don't initialize it, so it remains `undefined`.

At the time your HTML renders the promise isn't fulfilled yet, your `car` is still `undefined` but you try to access a property from it.

A couple solutions:

*preset it*:

```
cars: CarObject = new CarObject(); // or <CarObject>{}
```

*use the elvis operator in your template*:

```
 {{ cars?.stylesCount }}
```

*use `ngIf`*:

```
 <div *ngIf="cars">{{ cars.styleCount }}</div>
```

There are probably a couple of more ways to handle this case.

See my update at the bottom regarding your usage of the `async` pipe. It probably leads to errors as well in the way you're trying to use it.

---

Besides, i would suggest reading up on TypeScript types as well as general best practices for angular and typescript especially regarding the usage of models, interfaces and such. Also using Observables would be a good idea instead of Promises. 
There are some issues in your code, so this is just a hint, but elaborating on them has no place here i think and aren't the source of your problem.

Hope i could help.

---

Update:

*About your usage of the `async` pipe:*

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted.

You use it on an `array` of `CarObjects` which btw shouldn't be an array. 
Take a look at [the documentation for the async pipe for proper usage.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)

Comment: hey! Thanks so much for your response, however, I am still troubled. Yeah, I don't mind converting to observables, I'll do that now -> really simple to convert. However, you said there are issues in my code - which is what I'm trying to solve - I'm hoping you could elaborate a little more as I am new to Angular2 and would love to correct what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Well with the issues i meant were how you use the response and declare it as an array of your `CarsObject` instead of just an object. Using a constructor in your Car Model would be a proper way to do that, so your services creates instances of your cars and passes them back to your views. The async pipe binds to a Promise or Observable, not an array or object of your type. And then again this was just regarding to best practices, structure / maintainability. The error message you originally posted has nothing to do with it as far as i can tell. What happens if you follow one of the examples?

Comment: I used `<ng-container *ngIf="cars">{{ cars.styleCount }}</ng-container>` to no avail. the app doesn't load my data from the json response. By the way, I just converted my Promises to observable -> check edit code in a minute

Comment: how can I do without CarsObject? Rather just use an object if it's native to TS (or js)

Comment: i have updated my post regarding the async pipe. What do you mean by "the app doesn't load my data from the json response"? Do you get any errors? What's your output if you do a `console.log(this.cars)` right after you assigned it in your component? Can you try it with the `elvis` operator? I'm not sure if `ng-container` requires a html element inside, i updated my post to be safe because i dont have the time to test it right now.

Comment: 1. Used the elvis operator - no avail.
2. I don't get any error. I did `console.log(this.cars)` and received `undefined' from the Chrome Dev Console.

Comment: errors? try logging cars in your subscribe function, what do you get ? And please just remove the brackets from `CarObject[]`. You're not using arrays here.

Comment: No errors. Nothing. The only confirmation I have that the service works is the JSON response. How can I log a subscribe function?

Comment: Then log your return value in your service. What's `body.data` now? Wasn'it different before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135098/discussion-between-lexith-and-miguel).